# Can an Operations Research model optimize on a vector's indexes?

Tags: optimization, modeling

**Theoretical model**
Suppose that I have an input vector $E_{t}\in\mathbb R^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$

Suppose that I want to optimize $\displaystyle\max_{t,x} E_tx$.
That is, my decision variables are the vectors $x$ and $t$ of same dimension $n$. We optimize on the indexes of the input vector $E$.

Subject to some linear constraints $Ax\le b_1$ and $Bt \le b_2$, $\quad (A,B)\in\mathcal M_{n,n}(\mathbb R)^2$, $(b_1,b_2)\in (\mathbb R^n)^2$.

and some domain constraints: $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $t\in\{1,\dots,n\}^n$.

Is such model exist in any Operations Research formulation? MILP, ILP, MQLP etc.? The fact that the input vector is indexed by a decision variable is something I have not met yet.

**Numerical example** of such model would be:

$n = 3$

$E = (5,-1,3),\quad \forall i \in \{1,2,3\}$. Note that $E_i$ could be anything in $\mathbb R$.

$\displaystyle\max_{t,x} E_tx$

Without any constraint except domains constraints: $x\in \{0,1\}^3$ and $t\in\{1,2,3\}^3$.

An optimal solution here would be:

$x=(1,1,1)$ and $t=(1,1,1)$ which would give an objective of $5\times 3 =15$.

**Numerical example with $Bt\le b_2$** of such model would be:

$n = 3$

$E = (5,-1,3),\quad \forall i \in \{1,2,3\}$. Note that $E_i$ could be anything in $\mathbb R$.

$\displaystyle\max_{t,x} E_tx$

**Constraints**

$t_i\ge 2,\quad \forall i\in\{1,2,3\}$
$\sum x \le 2$

Domain constraints: $x\in \{0,1\}^3$ and $t\in\{1,2,3\}^3$.

An optimal solution here would be:

$x=(1,0,1)$ and $t=(3,2,3)$ which would give an objective of $3+3=6$.
There is another optimal solution of value $6$:
$x=(1,0,1)$ and $t=(3,3,3)$

Comment: What is the relation between $i$ and $t$? Are there the same things? It seems the value of the variable $t$ is defined based on $i$ in an ordinary sense!

Comment: @A.Omidi, I have changed my example to answer your question. $t$ and the values of $E_t$ are independant.

Comment: What is the motivation for the $c t \le b_2$ constraint?  Also isn't $b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @RobPratt, I have edited my question accordingly. Does this answer your comment?

Comment: In your example, $b_2$ is a vector but $c$ is a matrix.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks for spotting this mistake, it is corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with ILP/MILP by using a binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indexed over $\lbrace 1,\dots, n\rbrace \times \lbrace 1,\dots, n\rbrace,$ where $y_{i,j}=1$ if and only if the $i$-th component of $E$ is matched to the $j$-th component of $x.$ Constraints on $y$ are $\sum_i y_{i,j} = 1\, \forall j$ and $\sum_j y_{i,j} = 1\, \forall i.$

Your objective function is $\sum_{i,j} E_i x_j y_{i,j}.$ The second solution in your example would correspond to $y_{3,1}=y_{2,2}=y_{1,3}=1.$ The objective is quadratic but easy to linearize (by introducing more variables). How to linearize the product of two binaries has been answered (a few thousand times, I think) elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you modelize that $ct \le b_2$?

Comment: I have edited my question with an example for $ct\le b_2$

Comment: $y_{i,j}=1 \iff t_j = i.$ So $c't = \sum_j \sum_i c_j\cdot i \cdot y_{i,j}.$

Answer (score 1):

This is a complement to the answer given by @prubin.

I will start by restating the definition you presented, just for conciseness.

Let

- $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n^{n + 1}}$ be a "matrix";
- $t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}$ be an index of $E$, thus $E_t \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$;
- $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$; And
- $b_1, b_2, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The initial formulation was presented as:

$\max$ $E_t^T x$

s.t. $A x \leqslant b_1$ (1)

$c^i t^i \leqslant b_2^i \quad\quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ (2)

$t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}\quad$ (3)

$x \in \mathbb{B}^n$ (4)

**MIQP formulation**:

Let's consider the following variables.

- $e^i \in \mathbb{R}$ be a variable standing for $E_t^i$, such that $t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}$; And
- $y_t \in \mathbb{B}$ be a flag variable telling whether setting $t$ is selected.

$\max$ $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} e^i x^i$

s.t. (Constraints 1)

$e^i = \sum_{t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}} y_t E_t^i \quad\quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ (5)

$c^i \sum_{t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}} y_t t^i \leqslant b_2^i \quad\quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ (6)

$\sum_{t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}} y_t = 1$ (7)

(Constraints 4)

**MILP formulation**:

Now, we will linearize the previous objective function, and propose a MILP.
Let's consider the variable $z^i \in \mathbb{R}$ be a variable standing for $E_t^i x^i$, such that $t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}$ and $i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$.

$\max$ $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} z^i$

s.t. (Constraints 1, 5, 6, and 7)

$e^i - (1 - x^i) M \leqslant z^i \leqslant x^i M \quad\quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ (8)

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad z^i \leqslant e^i \quad\quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ (9)

(Constraints 4)

$z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (10)

We can take the constant $M$ as the largest entry of $E$.

As a takeaway, I would say that the toughest part is on the number of variables $y$, since the scope $t \in \mathbb{N}^{*n}_{\leqslant n}$ easily explodes.

Let me know case there is any error.

Comment: I called $E$ a "matrix" by not knowing better terminology, sorry but I'm not a mathematician ...